# params={'value': value}, django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'' value must be either True or False."]

Tags: django, model

this is my code i have just started learning ddjango and got stuck here. I added address and status a few days after the other columns i get this error

> params={'value': value}, django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'' value must be either True or False."]

```
from django.db import models


class product(models.Model):
    prodid = models.IntegerField(("ID"))
    name = models.CharField(("Product Name"), max_length=100,unique ="true")
    price = models.IntegerField()
    star = models.IntegerField()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name 


    class cart (models.Model):
        product = models.ForeignKey(product , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        quantity = models.IntegerField()
        address = models.CharField(("Address"), max_length=300, default='')
        status = models.BooleanField(default=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return product
```

Comment: name = models.CharField(("Product Name"), max_length=100, **unique=True**)

Comment: still got the same error i thing something is wrong in the cart class kindly check that

Comment: at first i got a default value error that i removed 
        status = models.BooleanField(default=True) 
but still the same error pops up everytime i makemigrations

Comment: The error is in name field,their use unique=True instead of unique="true"

Comment: sir @GilbeeshKosma i corrected that but the error still pops up

Comment: Well, apart from that your models are fine and I can generate migrations from it. What you try to do that triggers this error?

Comment: sir i sort out the problem i just deleted the migrations and then migrated again and it worked @Gasanov thanks for the concern  :)